# MicroSD card file system keeps getting corrupt for no obvious reason

Tags: sd-card, file-system, file-management

Since when I got my current phone (May 2018) I had to reformat my MicroSD card about 3-4 times, probably because of file system corruption. (It's a SanDisk 8GB one, for those who are wondering. And the previous owner had installed it on 2 devices, the first was a tablet and the second was my current phone, no problems with them. Guess I was cursed!...)

One day I turned on my phone and noticed that several apps that had been moved to the SD card were no longer functioning (toast notification saying "The app is not installed"). The other three times it just happened out of nowhere. Even today (at the time of writing), I just moved an app from the SD card back to the phone's internal storage, then the Settings app crashed. I think this also happened because of corruption.

When this happens, I cannot move/copy/edit files to the SD card and a small percentage of my files get corrupt. (Thank God this time only some useless pictures got corrupted!)

Can anyone tell me why my SD card's file system is getting corrupt out of nowhere almost constantly?

Comment: probably physical problem. Had same experience with different MicroSD cards. these cards work well on other devices, maybe the slot is too loose

Comment: @alecxs Yes, but my issue is that the same card was in the same phone before I got it and there was no issue. And on top of that, I haven't dropped the phone from any absurd height, the max is 50cm or lower I believe.

Comment: I have had this issue with some devices and cards, changing the card to a different, quality branded one can fix it sometimes. No matter the device, I have never had a Samsung EVO sd card fail, ever. I would also make sure you enable automatic backup of critical things, a good choice for photos is Google Photo app, it can automatically backup your photos to your Google account.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks for checking out. As for the backup, there is no issue with copying files *from* the SD card *to* the PC, so I am covered. The issue is if I try to copy/move/edit any files to/on the SD card.

Comment: Do you tend to wear the phone in a [back] pocket? Is that some correlation to the times it becomes corrupted? Phones do not like to be flexed in pockets, since it can loosen relevant connections.

Comment: @wbogacz No, I never ever put any device on the back pocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Almost 2 years later (because I forgot that this post even exists, sorry).*

A week after posting this question here, I ran some tests using h2testw. The microSD card turned out to be faulty. I got a new phone 2 months later and a new Kingston microSD card to go with it. Haven't had a problem since.